# Type 'any[] | Observable<any[]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, config, angular-formly, ngx-formly

Body:
I'm getting the following TypeScript error in my Angular application:

**error TS2322: Type 'any[] | Observable<any[]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
The error occurs in the following line of code:**

The error occurs in the following line of code:

**<p-autoComplete [suggestions]="to.options" placeholder="{{to.placeholder}}" (completeMethod)="search($event)">**

Here, to.options is of type 'any[] | Observable<any[]> | undefined', and it's causing a type mismatch error.

I have already tried explicitly specifying the type of to.options as any[] in the component code, but the error still persists.

How can I resolve this TypeScript error and ensure that the type of to.options is correctly assigned to type 'any[]'?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank yo
u!

I'm Trying add custom autocomplete in formly configuration

Comment: Please read through the [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.